# build a 2D lookup table from Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, broadcast, lookup-tables

I would like to convert a smaller dataframe to become a broadcast lookup table to be used inside the UDF of another larger dataframe. This smaller dataframe (*myLookupDf*) may look like something below:

```
+---+---+---+---+
| x | 90|100|101|
+---+---+---+---+
| 90|  1|  0|  0|
|100|  0|  1|  1|
|101|  0|  1|  1|
+---+---+---+---+
```

I want to use the first column as the first key, say x1, and the first row as the second key. x1 and x2 have the same elements. Ideally, the lookup table (*myLookupMap*) will be a Scala Map (or similar) and work like:

```
myLookupMap(90)(90) returns 1
myLookupMap(90)(101) returns 0
myLookupMap(100)(90) returns 0
myLookupMap(101)(100) return 1
etc.
```

So far, I manage to have:

```
val myLookupMap = myLookupDf.collect().map(r => Map(myLookupDf.columns.zip(r.toSeq):_*))
myLookupMap: Array[scala.collection.Map[String,Any]] = Array(Map(x -> 90, 90 -> 1, 100 -> 0, 101 -> 0), Map(x -> 100, 90 -> 0, 100 -> 1, 101 -> 1), Map(x -> 101, 90 -> 0, 100 -> 1, 101 -> 1))
```

which is an Array of Map and not exactly what is required. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: why are you converting the dataframe to maps? And how do you want to use the broadcasted df to another df?

Comment: As the lookup table is used by a UDF, it cannot be a dataframe. This approach is used to avoid a cartesian join of two dataframes, as the larger one could be massive.

Comment: I have answered below according to what I have understood from your explanations :) I hope the answer helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`collect()` always create `rdd` which is equivalent to `Array`. You have to find ways to collect the `arrays` as `maps`.

Given the `dataframe` as

```
scala> myLookupDf.show(false)
+---+---+---+---+
|x  |90 |100|101|
+---+---+---+---+
|90 |1  |0  |0  |
|100|0  |1  |1  |
|101|0  |1  |1  |
+---+---+---+---+
```

All you need are the header names other than `x` so you can do something like below

```
scala>     val header = myLookupDf.schema.fieldNames.tail
header: Array[String] = Array(90, 100, 101)
```

I am just modifying your `map` functions to get `Map` as the result

```
scala>     val myLookupMap = myLookupDf.rdd.map(r => {
     |       val row = r.toSeq
     |       (row.head, Map(header.zip(row.tail):_*))
     |     }).collectAsMap()
myLookupMap: scala.collection.Map[Any,scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any]] = Map(101 -> Map(90 -> 0, 100 -> 1, 101 -> 1), 100 -> Map(90 -> 0, 100 -> 1, 101 -> 1), 90 -> Map(90 -> 1, 100 -> 0, 101 -> 0))
```

You should see that you get the desired results.

```
scala> myLookupMap(90)(90.toString)
res1: Any = 1

scala> myLookupMap(90)(101.toString)
res2: Any = 0

scala> myLookupMap(100)(90.toString)
res3: Any = 0

scala> myLookupMap(101)(100.toString)
res4: Any = 1
```

Now you can pass the `myLookupMap` to your `udf` function

Comment: my pleasure @Jonathan :) thanks for acceptance :) you can upvote too when you would be eligible :)